# Windows wmic: list all available screen resolutions without using Powershell

Tags: windows, wmi, wmic

I am well aware that I can get all available screen modes in Powershell using `gwmi` - for example, as follows:

```
(gwmi -N "root\wmi" -Class WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes)[0].MonitorSourceModes | select {"$($_.HorizontalActivePixels)x$($_.VerticalActivePixels)"}
```

However, I would like to know if there is a simple way to do this in `cmd.exe` using just `wmic` and without using `grep` or `findstr` to filter out the `HorizontalActivePixels` and `VerticalActivePixels` properties. This is what I do at the moment.

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path wmimonitorlistedsupportedsourcemodes  get * /format:list | findstr ActivePixels
```

I know there are plenty of other solutions, but I would just like to know if wmic has a builtin way.

Comment: Answer: Negative. See [wmic documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic).

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this batch file :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Resolution using WMIC an Btch
@for /f "delims=" %%# in (
'"wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value"'
) do (
    set "%%#">nul
)
echo CurrentHorizontalResolution x CurrentVerticalResolution : %CurrentHorizontalResolution% x %CurrentVerticalResolution% 
pause
```

Comment: Nice batch, but the topic creator asked about available resolutions not current resolution...